# buildWhen in StoreConnector

Tags: flutter, redux, flutter-redux

I'm facing a problem that I can't solve.
There are two StoreConnectors on different screens, which are tied to 1 state.
How can I make it so that when the second StoreConnector is rendered, the first one is not rebuilt?
In Bloc this could be done using the buildWhen property of BlocBuilder.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ignoreChange`.

Demo code:

```
StoreConnector<AppState, MyViewModel>(
     distinct: true,
     ignoreChange: (state) {      
         return state.someVariable == theValueYouDontCare;
     },
     ...
 ),
```